# Python requests - post method - send image from CV2 - ndarray not working

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, python-requests, http-post, flask-restful

I have below Flask API server side code:

```
    def post(self):
        data = parser.parse_args()
        if not data['file']:
            abort(404, message="No images found")
        imagestr = data['file'].read()
        if imagestr:
            #convert string data to numpy array
            npimg = np.frombuffer(imagestr, np.uint8)
            # convert numpy array to image
            img = cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Client side code:

```
def detect(image):
    endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1/getimage"
    # imstring = base64.b64encode(cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1]).decode()
    # img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    # im = img_str.tostring()
    # jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    # print(jpg_as_text)
    data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tobytes()
    files = {'file':data}
    headers={"content-type":"image/jpg"}
    response = requests.post(endpoint, files=files, headers=headers)
    return response
```

For the API, I am able to successfully send image through CURL and get the response.

```
curl -X POST -F file=@input.jpg http://127.0.0.1/getimage
```

However, while I tried with client code, I am unable to send the images. I am seeing that no file is received at the server side:

```
{'file': None}
192.168.101.57 - - [17/Aug/2020 14:56:39] "POST /getimage HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Can someone please help on this?

Comment: in your `curl`you send it to the endpoint `/getimage` but the server log says `/detect` - check you're actually using the right endpoint

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [request docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) you should use the following approach to post files:

```
files = {'file': ('image.jpg', open('image.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpg', {'Expires': '0'})}
response = requests.post(endpoint, files=files)
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use this approach, as it allows me to send not only images but **any** numpy array with some compression to reduce size. (useful when let's say you want to send an array of images which is a 4d numpy array)

Client side code:

```
import io,zlib
def encode_ndarray(np_array):    #utility function
    bytestream = io.BytesIO()
    np.save(bytestream, np_array)
    uncompressed = bytestream.getvalue()
    compressed = zlib.compress(uncompressed,level=1)   #level can be 0-9, 0 means no compression
    return compressed

any_numpy_array = np.zeros((4,150,150,3))
encoded_array = encode_ndarray(any_numpy_array)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
resp = requests.post(endpoint, data=encoded_array,headers=headers)
```

Server side code:

```
def decode_ndarray(bytestream):    #utility function
    return np.load(io.BytesIO(zlib.decompress(bytestream)))

@app.route("/getimage", methods=['POST'])
def function():
    r = request
    any_numpy_array = decode_ndarray(r.data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer